# flexbox exclude last item from nowrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have set flexbox nowrap on my container. At specific width, using media queries, I would like to push last item in container (item 3) into new line so it does not influence flex items in container. Is this possible with css, without javascript? I can use some additional html markup if necessary.

Note: there could be more than 3 items in container, this is just an example with 3 items.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM 1
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM 2
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM 3
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: disable the wrap and make the last element width:100% ?

Comment: but I want to have wram, only exclude last itme

Comment: you said *would like to push last item in container (item 3) into new line*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the existing markup, and when using `nowrap`, the only way to exclude the last item at given width would be to make it `position: absolute`.

That would on the other hand need a script to adjust the `container`'s height, to prevent elements later in markup to end up beneath it (the positioned one).

```css
.flex-parent {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .flex-item:last-child {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
  }  
}


/* just for this demo, to create space between "container"'s */
.container + .container {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container flex-parent">
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM 1
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM 2
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM 3
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM Last
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container flex-parent">
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM 1
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM 2
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM 3
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM 4
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM 5
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM Last
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container flex-parent">
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM 1
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM 2
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM Last
  </div>
</div>
```

Given a markup change is allowed, one solution to accomplish that is to wrap all but the last item in a parent of their own, and then toggle `flex-direction` with your media query.

To make *space-between* work in both cases (wrapped/notwrapped), I use a `pseudo` element, combined with making the inner `flex-parent` fill the remaining space using `flex: 1`

Stack snippet

```css
.flex-parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.container .flex-parent {
  flex: 1;
}
.container .flex-parent::after {
  content: '';
}  

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .container.flex-parent {
    flex-direction: column;
  }  
  .container .flex-parent::after {
    display: none;
  }  
}


/* just for this demo, to create space between "container"'s */
.container + .container {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container flex-parent">
  <div class="flex-item flex-parent">
    <div class="flex-item">
      ITEM 1
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      ITEM 2
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      ITEM 3
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM Last
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container flex-parent">
  <div class="flex-item flex-parent">
    <div class="flex-item">
      ITEM 1
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      ITEM 2
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      ITEM 3
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      ITEM 4
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      ITEM 5
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM Last
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container flex-parent">
  <div class="flex-item flex-parent">
    <div class="flex-item">
      ITEM 1
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      ITEM 2
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM Last
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like this idea with additional markup, I think its most bulletproof. I can add more markup so it fits my needs. I did not needed space-between, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can just disable nowrap in the media query and adjust the flex-basis of your items. This can be used if you have a known number of elements.

Please make sure, to have set `flex-grow: 0;` on your `.flex-item` or they might get scaled to full width of your container.

If you have a undefined count of elements, you might

Sniped with `flex-grow:0`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding:10px 0;
}

.container .flex-item{
  flex-basis:33%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.flexrow .flex-item {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.dynamic .flex-item {
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
.onlythird  .flex-item, .onlylast .flex-item {
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis:0;
  overflow:auto;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .container .flex-item{
    flex-basis:50%;
  }
  
  .onlythird  .flex-item, .onlylast .flex-item {
    flex-basis: 0;
  }
  .onlylast .flex-item:last-child {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
  .onlythird  .flex-item:nth-child(3) {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    order:1;
  }
}

/* COLORS */

.flex-item {
  background: green;
}
.flex-item + .flex-item {
  background: red;
}
.flex-item + .flex-item + .flex-item {
  background: blue;
}
.flex-item + .flex-item + .flex-item + .flex-item {
  background: yellow;
}
.flex-item + .flex-item + .flex-item + .flex-item + .flex-item {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<h1>Without grow</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM 1
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM 2
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM 3
  </div>
</div>

<h1>With grow</h1>
<div class="container flexrow">
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM 1
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM 2
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM 3
  </div>
</div>

<h1>Dynamic count</h1>
<div class="container dynamic">
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM 1
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM 2
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM 3
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM 4
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM 5
  </div>
</div>

<h1>Dynamic count ONLY break last item</h1>
<div class="container onlylast">
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM 1
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM 2
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM 3
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM 4
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM 5
  </div>
</div>


<h1>Dynamic count ONLY break 3. item</h1>
<div class="container onlythird">
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM 1 asdasdasdasdasdasdasfasdasdsdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasfasdasd
    asdasda sd asd asd sfasdf asdfasdfasd  fasd fsda fasd fsd fsd fasdf asdf asdf sdaf 
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM 2
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM 3
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM 4
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    ITEM 5
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this hardocded to 3 items in container or I am seeing wrong?

Comment: Just the colors to see the effect of the `flex-grow` effects. this layout is freely extendable with other `.flex-item` BUT You have to change the `flex-basis` in the nowrap version, or add a `flex-shrink` property. do you want it to be flexible?

Comment: Ok have added the dynamic item count code. If you have questions please ask ;)